# Can I know why my question on accuracy of tax returns was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

It was put up with snap shots of the actual tax documents minus the information like SSN etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted your question.  You missed removing something important.  Not your SSN, something else.

Check your snapshot again, *carefully,* and you should spot what I spotted.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got that. Thanks Chris!

Comment: @Harpreet Feel free to repost with information that should not be shared blurred or blacked out.

Comment: @Alex: I have reposted by erasing that information. Thanks!

Comment: @Harpreet:  I was also able to get imgur.com to delete the original unblurred images by filing a removal request.